# Analog magazine story from late 60s/early 70s. Zen/Psychic culture defeats an invasion

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This was a short story. I think it was in *Analog*, probably in the late 60s or early 70s.

A planet of meditative/mindful pacifists is being invaded by evil aliens who threaten mass murder. The adults seem to be doing nothing, so local youths get impatient and summon up storms & other large-scale destructive physical phenomena to repel the invaders. The local adults scold them for making a big mess and not being patient/peaceful enough.

Comment: It's a signature.  I Googled zhurnaly and got this guy's blog.

Comment: @DaphneB - If you see signatures, you should remove them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this may be "[Facts to Fit the Theory](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?45522)" by Christopher Anvil.  I found it in the collection "[Interstellar Patrol II - The Federation of Humanity](http://www.baen.com/Chapters/0743498925/0743498925.htm)"  It can be found [here](http://hell.pl/szymon/Baen/The%20Baltic%20War/Interstellar%20Patrol%20II-The%20Federation%20of%20Humanity/0743498925___8.htm).

This is a short story, published in 1966, in ANALOG.  There is a planet under threat by evil alien invaders, and the inhabitants of the planet were both pacifists (practicing 'self-control') and opposed to the methods of the Federation, who was otherwise offering to bring them under protection.  There is a series of hijinks, wherein the federation tries to get a treaty signed (to save them from the invaders) but which are mysteriously foiled by the inhabitants, due to religious objections.

The invasion happens, or at least the evil aliens land, but each aggressive act they attempt is foiled by seemingly-natural causes (while the inhabitants fail to otherwise fight back), until finally the younger colonists lose their tempers and summon storms & the like to interrupt a large ceremony with a planned atrocity (meant to subdue any resistance).  The local adults do scold them for lack of self control and the other damage caused by the large storms.  The story ends with the federation observers trying to figure out how to report this turn of events.

Comment: Thank you, @Megha - yes, that's certainly it - mission accomplished (^_^) ...

Comment: @zhurnaly - great!  glad I could help.